# Diffuse priors Bayes Factor

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, prior, posterior, bayes-factors

In textbooks I always read that it is necessary to have a proper prior on the parameter that we want to test with Bayes factor, otherwise we would always posteriori favor the model with less parameters.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your question. Can you please clarify the points that we brought up in the comments to @RobinRyder's answer? We're confused about whether you mean to ask about improper/flat priors or just very wide/"diffuse" priors (that are still proper).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The small model isn't necessarily favoured; rather, if you use an improper prior, the Bayes factor is not uniquely defined, because an improper prior is defined up to a multiplicative constant.

The Bayes factor is the ratio of the marginal likelihoods of your two models. With prior $\pi$ and likelihood $L$, you can write the marginal likelihood of a model as 
$$m(y)=\int \pi(\theta) L(\theta;x)d\theta.$$

If your prior is improper, nothing stops you from replacing $\pi(\theta)$ by $K\cdot \pi(\theta)$, thus multiplying the marginal likelihood by an arbitrary constant $K$. Thus your Bayes factor can take any value in $\mathbb R_+$.

This doesn't happen with proper priors: since they must integrate to 1, you cannot multiply them by $K$.

Comment: I don't think the question was about using an improper prior, but just a very wide/diffuse prior.

Comment: @JakeWestfall - the OP does say "proper prior", not "diffuse prior".

Comment: @jbowman I guess it's ambiguous: the title says "diffuse" but the actual text talks about a "proper" prior. Certainly the conclusion that the OP mentioned is only valid in the case of wide/diffuse priors and not improper priors (as Robin rightly points out), which makes me think they mean to ask about wide/diffuse priors. But the OP should clarify.

Comment: @JakeWestfall - good points, both.

Comment: @JakeWestfall Ah yes, thanks for pointing that out. I focused on the text of the question; I hadn't noticed the discrepancy between the title and the text. You are right that my answer doesn't apply to a diffuse prior, only to an improper prior.